# Css of listing with photos is not aligned

Tags: php, html, css

I created a list with two queries. A list of the first 8 photos and the other lists the last 8 photos of the table.
But the css of the second query list does not appear well.

the second query only appears when you click the "view more categories" button
the code is:

```
 <div class="row">
    <?php
    $query=mysqli_query($db,"select id_album, nome, foto from albuns order by id_album ASC limit 8");
    while($cat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="portfolio-item">
            <p class="imgDescription"> <?php echo $cat['nome'];?> </p>
              <a>
                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="<?php echo $cat['foto'];?>" onClick="location.href='listagem_album.php?id=<?php echo $cat['id_album'];?>'">
                </a>
             </div>
           </div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php
        $query=mysqli_query($db,"select id_album, nome, foto from albuns order by id_album DESC limit 8");?>
          <div id="fotos" style="display:none"> <?php
             while($cat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                   <div class="portfolio-item">
                     <p class="imgDescription"> <?php echo $cat['nome'];?> </p>
                       <a>
                        <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="<?php echo $cat['foto'];?>" onClick="location.href='listagem_album.php?id=<?php echo $cat['id_album'];?>'">
                       </a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               <?php } ?>
             </div>
           </div>
           <!-- /.row (nested) -->
           <div id="button"><a class="btn btn-dark">View More Categories</a>                 </div>
```

Comment: Could you add the final output as a JS Fiddle, it will make it a lot easier to work out

Comment: Indeed PHP is of no use here...we need the output HTML & CSS.

Comment: Add HTML, JS and CSS code instead of PHP.

Comment: @Alok How can i do that with JS. I only know how do that with PHP. Thank's